# Create a view and should not allow any data manipulation language operations

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, date, oracle-apex

Q: Create a view called `TITLE_NOTRETURNED` to show the movie titles and
media_id of the media not returned yet. The view should not allow any data manipulation language operations.

I need to create view as the attached question but it return error that Im missing expressions.

Rental History table:
rentaldate, returndate

Media table:
media id, format

Movies table:
title id, title

My code:

```
CREATE VIEW TITLE_NOTRETURNED AS
SELECT mov.title, m.mediaid, r.rentaldate
FROM Movies mov, Media m, rental_history r
WHERE mov.titleid = m.titleid
AND m.mediaid = r.mediaid
AND r.returndate > (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, getdate() )
);
```

Also, Ive tried before to change rental_history r to rentaldate r, but it doesn't work also.

ERD:

[image]

Comment: Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: First of all, change to modern ANSI join Syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is Oracle, it gives **ORA-00936: missing expression** because

```
select convert(date, getdate())
```

is missing a `from` clause.

Once you've fixed that, [`convert`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CONVERT.html#GUID-C8BA0657-61C8-4964-A4CB-9292390853F6) is for character sets, not dates, `date` is a keyword for introducing a [date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) such as `date '2020-12-23'`, and there's no `getdate()` function (unless you've written  one yourself).

A fixed version (including the requirement to prevent DML) would be:

```
create or replace view title_not_returned as
select mov.title, m.mediaid, r.rentaldate
from   movies mov
       join media m on m.titleid = mov.titleid
       join rental_history r on r.mediaid = m.mediaid
where  r.returndate > trunc(sysdate)
with read only;
```

How are rental return dates populated, by the way? If they default to some distant future date such as 31st Dec 9999 and are then updated to the actual date when returned, this will work (but perhaps the special date should be used in the view). If they start out null, indicating not yet returned, you won't get any results.